# Zero element of Ext$^n$ groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-categories

In every Abelian category, given a non-negative integer $n$ and objects $A$ and $B$, one can define the (Yoneda) Ext-set $\text{Ext}^n(B,A)$. The construction is explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Construction_of_Ext_in_abelian_categories) Wikipedia page. What is not explained, however, is how to make these sets into Abelian groups. The operation is defined, but what is the zero element? For $n=1$ there is an obvious choice of a trivial exact sequence, namely, the split exact sequence
$$0 \to A \to A \oplus B \to B \to 0$$
with the standard maps. But I wonder how a trivial exact sequence of the form
$$0 \to A \to ? \to ? \to B \to 0$$
should look like. And the same for higher $n$.

Comment: How about $0\to A\to A\to B\to B\to 0$ with the middle homomorphism zero?

Comment: The Wikipedia article defines Baer sum, so you can look at what the identity element of Baer sum must look like.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, but the operation is only defined up to equivalence, which makes it hard for general $n$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Your suggestion makes sense for $n=2$, but how do you generalize it? Shouldn’t it look more like a split exact sequence?

Comment: For higher $n$ my guess would be $0 \to A \to A \to 0 \to \cdots \to 0 \to B \to B \to 0$.

Comment: Indeed @DanielSchepler, that is the Yoneda product of a bunch of split s. e. sequences, each of which is zero in Ext${}^1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How is the zero sequence in Ext$^n(B,A)$ a Yoneda product of split exact sequences? Yoneda product is like composition, you need the final term of a sequence and the initial term of the next to agree, don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are objects in the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, the (equivalence class) of the exact sequence
$$0\to A\to A\oplus B\to B\to 0$$
is the zero object in $\text{Ext}^{1}(B,A)$.

For $n>1$, the zero object of $\text{Ext}^{n}(B,A)$ is the (equivalence class) of the sequence

$$0 \to A\to A \to 0 \to\cdots\to 0\to B\to B\to 0$$
where the maps $A\to A$ and $B\to B$ are the identity.

The group structure on both is a bit fiddly. Consider the maps $\Delta:A\to A\oplus A$ given by $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$  and $\nabla:A\oplus A\to A$ given by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. The operation $+$ on $\text{Ext}^{i}(B,A)$ is $$\textbf{E}_{1}+\textbf{E}_{2} := \nabla (\textbf{E}_{1}\oplus\textbf{E}_{2})\Delta$$
where the direct sum is what you expect.

A proof that these form an abelian group can be found in Chapter 7 (called Extensions) of book [Theory of Categories](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/mitchell.pdf) by Mitchell. It also shows that  these coincide with the usual derived functor definition of Ext groups.

Answer (score 5):

First one word of caution: for a general abelian category, even $\mathrm{Ext}^1(X,Y)$ can fail to be a *set*.

As people have pointed out above, the zero element in $\mathrm{Ext}^2(D,A)$ is represented by the four term exact sequence
$$ 0 \to A \xrightarrow{1} A \xrightarrow{0} D \xrightarrow{1} D \to 0. $$
That still leaves the question of whether a given four term sequence is zero. For this there is the following nice answer. Given an exact sequence
$$ \eta\colon 0 \to A \to B \to C \to D \to 0, $$
let $I$ be the image of the map $C\to D$. Then $\eta$ is zero in $\mathrm{Ext}^2(D,A)$ if and only if there exists an object $X$ fitting into an exact commutative diagram
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
@.@. 0 @. 0\\
@.@. @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> I @>>> 0\\
@. @| @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> A @>>> X @>>> C @>>> 0\\
@.@. @VVV @VVV\\
@.@. D @= D\\
@.@. @VVV @VVV\\
@.@. 0 @. 0
\end{CD} $$
In fact, given another exact sequence
$$ \eta' \colon 0 \to A \to B' \to C' \to D \to 0 $$
we have that $\eta=\eta'$ in $\mathrm{Ext}^2(D,A)$ if and only if there exists an object $X$ fitting into the exact commutative diagram
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> I @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> B' @>>> X @>>> C @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>> I' @>>> C' @>>> D @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0
\end{CD} $$

Comment: Thanks ! Can you please give a reference where this is proven ?

Comment: I don't know anywhere other than my notes where it is formulated like this, but it follows from the fact that two long exact sequences represent the same extension class if and only if they are related by a cospan (this holds for all $n$). For example, from the last diagram we get maps from both our original sequences to $0\to A\to X\to C\oplus C'\to D\to 0$, and hence we get a cospan.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have chosen the other one as it addresses my question more directly (for all $n$), as it was originally formulated. But I do find your explanation very useful and interesting! Can your argument be extended to higher values of $n$?