# Additive inverse and transitivity in Ext$^n(B,A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336214/356190) question and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Construction_of_Ext_in_abelian_categories) Wikipedia page, I have now understood the definitions of the Baer sum and of the zero element in Ext$^n(B,A)$. But I still have a couple of questions that I could not find an answer to.

1. I still do not understand how to define the additive inverse of a sequence for $n \ge 2$. I have tried to generalize the definition used for $n=1$, but without success. Any hints?
2. The definition of equivalence of sequences on the Wikipedia page (which is basically just the existence of a chain map which is the identity on the two extremes) seems very weak, if compared to what I have found in the literature (Bourbaki, MacLane). Above all, it is not at all clear to me why this condition should satisfy transitivity.

Comment: For 2, note that reflexivity is obvious; and for the rest note that wiki states "the equivalence relation generated by"

Comment: @Max Thanks, I wanted to say transitivity. But your remark makes it clear anyway :) I had missed the "generated by"

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. In any case this is taken care of by "equivalence relation generated by".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an additive inverse of $0\to A\to C_1\to\cdots\to C_n\to B\to 0$ in
$\text{Ext}^n(B,A)$
just replace one of the maps $A\to C_1$, $C_1\to C_2,\ldots,C_n\to B$ by its negative.

Comment: Is this easy to see? Let $n=2$. According to Bourbaki, if what you claim is true I should be able to find a third sequence "fitting" between the trivial sequence $0 \to A \to A \to B \to B \to 0$ and the Baer sum $0 \to A \to C_1 \sqcup_A C_1 \overset{(+,-)}{\to} C_2 \times_B C_2 \to B \to 0$, meaning that both sequences should have a map of complexes to the third sequence, with identities at the extremes. I have tried to find such a third sequence, but there's always some arrow that does not work...

Comment: You only need to check for $n=1$, since the $n$-fold extension is a Yoneda product of $n$ s.e. sequences.

Comment: How‘s that? To form a Yoneda product of two SESs, don’t you need the last object of one to coincide with the first object of the other?

Comment: oh, ok, do you just split the LESs into SESs as usual? Fine. But I think that it would still be instructive to prove it directly, since I didn’t prove anything about the properties of the Yoneda product. Do you have any hint?